# Cannot define variable from one function into another one

Tags: python, undefined

I cannot use variables from one function in another one. **I'm trying to use these two:**

```
    def b(df):
     macd=df['Close'].ewm(span=12, ignore_na=False).mean()- 
     df['Close'].ewm(span=26,ignore_na=False).mean() 
     return macd

    def b1(df):
     signal=df.rolling(window=9).mean()
     return signal
```

**in**

```
    def pls(df, macd, signal):
     macd=b(df)
     signal=b1(df)
     kodas(AMZN, macd, signal, 10000, 1, 1)
     balance=kodas(df, macd, signal, 10000, 1, 1)
     profitai=np.diff(balance)
     return macd, signal
```

but eventually I'm getting this error **name 'macd' is not defined** when I do
`pls(AMZN, macd, signal, balance, profitai)`. I'm sure that it will happen also with 'signal' and 'balance'. I understand that I didn't define 'macd' outside function but I'm going to calculate 'macd' not for one STOCK data, so I must make a function that code wouldn't be repeated a thousand times. So, my question is **what should I do in this situation that I could use variables from one function in another one?**
**This is full code:**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

def failas(df):
 coltsla=['Date', 'Time' , 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
 dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
 df = pd.read_csv(df, parse_dates={'Datetime': ['Date', 'Time']}, header=0, names=coltsla)
return df

def failas1(df):
 coltsla=['Date', 'Time' , 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
 dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
 df = pd.read_csv(df, parse_dates={'Datetime': ['Date', 'Time']}, skiprows=2, header=0,names=coltsla)
 return df

AMZN=failas("/content/drive/My Drive/AMZN.csv")
AMZN1=failas1("/content/drive/My Drive/AMZN.csv")

def b(df):
 macd=df['Close'].ewm(span=12, ignore_na=False).mean()- 
 df['Close'].ewm(span=26,ignore_na=False).mean() 
 return macd

def b1(df):
 signal=df.rolling(window=9).mean()
 return signal

def kodas(df, macd, signal, pradzia=10000, buyk=1, macdk=1):
 a=pd.Series(df['Close'])

 balance=[]
 money=pradzia
 kiekis=0
 lieka=0
 uzdarbis=0
 perkame=0
 taxsuma=100

for i in range(1, len(df)):
#Pirkimas
 if (macd[i] > signal[i] and macd[i-1] <= signal[i-1]):
  kiekis=money//(a[i]*buyk) 
  perkame=a[i]*buyk*kiekis
  lieka=money-perkame
 #TakeProfit
 if (macd[i] < signal[i]*macdk and macd[i-1] >= signal[i-1]*macdk):
  parduodame=kiekis*(a[i])
  uzdarbis=parduodame-perkame+lieka-taxsuma
  money=money+uzdarbis
 #Stoploss
 if (macd[i] > signal[i] and macd[i-1] <= signal[i-1] and a[i] < (df['High'][i])*0.945 or macd[i] < 
  signal[i] and macd[i-1] >= signal[i-1] and a[i] < (df['High'][i])*0.945):  
  parduodame=kiekis*(a[i])
  uzdarbis=parduodame-perkame+lieka-taxsuma
  money=money+uzdarbis
 balance.append(money-10000)
return balance

def pls(df, macd, signal):
 macd=b(df)
 signal=b1(df)
 kodas(AMZN, macd, signal, 10000, 1, 1)
 balance=kodas(df, macd, signal, 10000, 1, 1)
 profitai=np.diff(balance)
 return macd, signal

pls(AMZN, macd, signal, balance, profitai)
plt.plot(AMZN1['Datetime'], profitai.cumsum())
```

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere you define a variable named `macd` you are defining it at "function scope".  That means that that variable will only exist for as long as that function is executing.  When the function exits, the `macd` variable is gone.  In some cases you're defining `macd` as a local variable in the function, and other times you're defining it as a parameter to the function, but the result is the same either way.  Both ways of defining the variable cause it to be defined at the level of a single function, which means that when the function ends, that variable no longer exists.  So you can't "use a variable defined in one function in another function".  It doesn't work that way due to the scoping rules of the language.

Where you're trying to use the `macd` variable and are getting the error is "global scope".  You haven't defined a variable named `macd` at that scope level.  That's why you're getting the error.

You need to figure out a way to get the value you're interested out to the global scope.  You can best do this by having one of your functions return it as the function's return value.  You can then set a global variable named `macd` to be the result of calling that function, and then you can pass that variable into the `pls` function.

The `b` function returns `macd` but it takes a parameter `df`, which you don't define at the global scope either.  But just to illustrate, say you did somehow already have a value for `df` at the global scope.  Then your code might look like this:

```
df = ???

...

macd = b(df) # <- `macd` variable being defined at the global scope
pls(AMZN, macd, signal, balance, profitai)
plt.plot(AMZN1['Datetime'], profitai.cumsum())
```

This code isn't going to run, however, since you will have the same problem with the rest of your parameters to the `pls` function, and with a value for `profitai` as well.

What I'm thinking you really want to do is bring up the code in the `pls` function to the global scope and get rid of that function.  Also, you can get a value for `df` by calling `failas1`.  That function accepts a value `df` as a parameter, which doesn't make sense because the function computes a value for `df`.  We can therefore pass in anything for that parameter, as it isn't used. With those ideas, we come up with:

```
df = failas1(None)

macd = b(df)
signal = b1(df)
kodas(AMZN, macd, signal, 10000, 1, 1)
balance = kodas(df, macd, signal, 10000, 1, 1)
profitai = np.diff(balance)

plt.plot(AMZN1['Datetime'], profitai.cumsum())
```

There were a few indentation errors in your code that I had to fix as well.  Once I did that, and rearranged the bottom of the code as above, then all the symbol definitions seemed to match up pretty well. I didn't try to run the code.  There are a few other places where you pass in a parameter to a function, but then have the function compute that value.  In those cases, you probably want to remove the parameter from the function signature.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Steve but I've already tried that code you suggested. But I have to use those functions for 10 dataframe like:

    AMZN=failas("/content/drive/My Drive/AMZN.csv")
    MSFT=failas("/content/drive/My Drive/MSFT.csv")
    NFLX=failas("/content/drive/My Drive/NFLX.csv")
    NKE=failas("/content/drive/My Drive/NKE.csv")
    OIL=failas("/content/drive/My Drive/OIL.csv")
    .....

So, if I'm going to use that code for 10 dataframes, I'll have to write same code 10 times but just change df argument. But as I understand, that's the only way in this situation?